# How are molded-case circuit breaker trip ratings determined?

Tags: power

Circuit breakers and fuses have trip curves which describe how quickly they interrupt various currents. How does the manufacturer of a molded-case circuit breaker choose one value of current to represent the product? In other words, how would you determine the trip rating of this molded-case breaker given its trip curve?

[image: example trip curve]

Answer (score 2):

Did more research.

Table 7.1.2.2.1 of [UL 489](http://ulstandardsinfonet.ul.com/scopes/scopes.asp?fn=0489.html) lists the maximum automatic tripping time at 200% of the rated current.

For example, breakers rated 101-150 Amps must trip within 8 minutes (480 seconds) at 200% of their rating. Since at 480 seconds this breaker has interrupted about 300 Amps, this breaker is probably rated 150 or 125 Amps.

Comment: The rated current of this breaker is what it can sustain 'indefinitely', a little over 150A from the graph, the UL specification indicates the maximum current after some 'generous startup' time.  The highest 20kA (1-30kA) value is for a local short and the 2kA (1-3kA) for a short at the end of a correctly rated cable.

Answer (score 0):

The lower range (0.02 seconds) is a magnetic effect. It is about 1 cycle of a 50/60 Hz AC. So once the current is enough to cause that (here about 3 kA), it is a pretty well-defined time.

Comment: Does that tell me the trip rating? 

(Also, I think you meant 3 kA as the beginning of the instantaneous region.)