# How can I provide time-controlled current protection?

Tags: timer, safety, protection, fuses, circuit-protection

I need a component name or solution. I have a fan motor that I run with AC. I am controlling with MCU and driver.

Operation logic:

0.75 s on, 9.25 s off.

My circuit works flawlessly with this logic. But, I need a protection one component or solution or fuse.

If current flows through this fuse for more than 0.75 seconds, the fuse should blow. (Current Max: 10 A RMS.)

In summary, is there a time-controlled fuse or component?

Comment: that simply sounds like a slow-blow fuse?

Comment: Is it synchronized to the line? That turn on and off duty may not be reflected to the fan accurately anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Basically every modern circuit breaker is an ["inverse-time" breaker with a trip curve](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/20286/how-are-molded-case-circuit-breaker-trip-ratings-determined).

So all you need to do is select a breaker such that your intermittent usage and duty cycle will be a good fit to the breaker's trip curve.

But you should also pause to think about the point of a breaker.  It's to protect lives, and equipment from destruction due to malfunction... not to assure in-spec operation.

Suppose you have a 10A fan motor in an incubator for orphan kittens.  It can run at 10A all day without destruction or starting a fire.  But if it did, it would annoy the kittens, so not good for the operation.  The appropriate breaker there is 10 amps or even 15 amps. Because it isn't the breaker's job to assure the kittens' comfort, that's the job of the regular control system.  The breaker's job is to prevent a fire if the fan shorts out.

Answer (score 0):

How about simple crowbar? You didn’t mention the AC voltage level, but if it’s a mains 230v you can affort a series shunt for current measurement without amlification.
R2,C1 sets the delay.

[image]